# QString debug information missing in not all projects in solution

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and QT 5 with about 50 projects.
Every now and then in project A the debug information for a QString is 
Name: QString, value: QString (12) and project B the exact name and value is listed in the autos window.

Rebuilding project A does not seem to help. The QT visualizers are ok, otherwise the information for project B would not have been displayed in the same debug session.

Does anybody have a clue why this occurs and how to solve it?

Tried:
1. Rebuilding
2. Deleting intermediate files and output files